# Non Communicating Staff

Tags: work-environment

I am in IT. I am responsible for 5 offices and 220 personnel for a local medical practice. I have been the sole IT person for over 2 years. I answer support calls and e-mails from the whole practice. There is one person out of the entire company that refuses to e-mail, call, or otherwise contact me for support with their electronics. Each time I have had to deal with her, she refuses to allow me to work on her equipment. I have to get the management involved each time I need to update, replace, repair, install software, etc. I have complained of this to management and they tell me she is how she is and live with it. What can I do to make some headway with this individual??

Comment: How does this person get support, then? And is it *her* equipment, as in BYOD, or does it belong to the practice? 5 offices/220 people is a lot for one IT person.

Comment: I don't get it, why do you need to make headway with this individual? I assume that when she has a problem, she would ask you to resolve it, rather than you constantly checking on her to see if she has a problem. So if she refuses to let you solve her problem, let her be.

Comment: Just a random thought, but is it possible that the person is question is doing things on their company equipment that is not to the benefit of the company and are in fact trying to hide their actions?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere that won't work if it's a phone, tablet or laptop and she takes it with her when she leaves the office.

Comment: Can you remote in to the PC after hours?

Answer (score 9):

The first thing you need to do is straighten out a misconception.

It is not *HER* equipment.  It belongs to the company, and the company has given you responsibility (and thus authority) for maintaining it.  *HER* role is to *OPERATE* the equipment.  She is limited to that role, only.

Sometimes you need to take an authoritarian approach.  Some will argue that it leads to conflict, but to me, she has initiated and is maintaining this conflict.

The minutia of how to implement this is not important here.  I am going to assume that you have not given her administrative access to any workstations, and that you have the ability to remotely control this machine through both remote desktop access and appropriate domain policies (yes, showing my Microsoft bias, here).

When it comes to hardware, you need to communicate with EVERY office's ENTIRE (affected) staff that you are going to be doing MANDATORY configuration changes a couple of days ahead of time, and that if there are specific blocks of time that would not work well, please let you know.  Send it to all appropriate management staff, as well.

Then, privately, send a message to the direct supervisor and manager, saying, "As you know, Ms. Pita is difficult to work with in these situations.  I will contact you first, when I am on-site, so that you can help mitigate her ongoing issues with these required procedures."

They're the managers - this is their problem to deal with.  *YOUR* problem to deal with is that you have allowed the perception to continue that you don't have the authority to do this.  You're going to have to be able to be a little more "rigid" when necessary.

I know there will be several "Huggy-Bunny" types who will say that you need to find some sort of consensus.  No, you don't.  You have your job to do, and Ms. Pita has hers.  You don't stand in the way of her doing her work, and you should not accept her standing in the way of you doing yours.

From a psychology standpoint:  This is just flat bullying on Ms. Pita's part.  It's hard to recognize because in most Western cultures, women are pressured into being consensus-builders rather than independent.  However, both genders are equally represented in the "jackass" category.  Don't ever forget that.

Comment: Take the hardline approach - if she won't allow software and antivirus updates to be installed, don't let the PC on the network as it's now a security risk.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - That's the difference:  You don't wait to have management back you up.  If you have to get that, you don't have authority.  You act as though you have the authority, and if someone in management pushes back, you make them justify it.  If you've been given responsibility, then you've been given authority.  If you're denied authority, then you make it clear to them you no longer have responsibility.  They go hand-in-hand, and sometimes, you have to be assertive.

Comment: @WesleyLong Joe does have a point here. Management could perceive this move the wrong way or that now both sides are actively in conflict. I am not saying you are wrong; I am saying that the situation needs to be approached with tactfulness and diplomacy as to avoid these issues. Several of which have already been suggested (Ex. do the maintenance during off hours).

Answer (score 2):

Just do your job, if you have to proactively do something to her machine then inform her manager and let them set up timeframe etc,.. Otherwise don't do anything unless requested by her manager.

I support multiple networks and that's the only way to do it efficiently. You shouldn't be the first point of contact for staff with IT issues. Everything should come from management.

I don't know or care if the staff member doesn't want me working on it. it comes through their manager, if I show up and they're not ready for me, hard luck. If I don't have a password and it's not a domain, I just hack in, remove/change their password and leave them a note. Time is precious.

One of a managers main roles is to be a buffer between his/her team members and the rest of the World, so let them do their role and concentrate on yours.

Unsure how others handle it, but I always as IT support keep myself at arms length from staff members. I'm friendly but that's it. Because at any time I may be called in to investigate them and my findings have in the past gotten people reprimanded or fired. So the way I do things, I would barely notice this lady who is giving you problems because NO ONE calls me for support. They call their manager, and the manager calls me.

It's not hard line, it's efficiency, If you're dealing with so many computers and peripherals, you don't waste time playing social games. Particularly if it's multiple locations.

I support multiple widely dispersed companies, one of which operates in a neighbouring country as well. If I get there and they're not ready, too bad, I need to get the job done and on a flight back asap. If the manager can't organise that, he/she will be the one I complain about, not the staff member. The staff member is the managers problem, not mine.

Comment: A little bit of a "hard line" approach wouldn't you say? Might be better to not be as "friendly" (sarcasm there) as you state and to perhaps try some interpersonal skills or just let the OP's Manager handle the issue stating that this individual is causing him delays/gridlock to keep the company's IT resources running appropriately and can be a serious liability.

Comment: @B1313 heirachy is there for a reason, one of the reasons is to take care of exactly these sorts of issues.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you, I am just saying you can catch more flies with honey than with vinegar. Being nice to an employee tends to get them to cooperate a little more so then if you were not exactly the friendliest of IT support personal.

Comment: @B1313 whatever works for you (Y)

Answer (score -1):

How is she doing her Job?

I would say the simplest is to give her a mail saying:

You seem to be uncomfortable with having regular updates for your system as mandated by the company's standard procedures. I understood from your statements that you require unsupported configurations for your work, and that you have agreed this with (Name of CIO/Manager/Department head). Please make appointments for maintenance windows as you see it fit for the support team to personally attend to your machine when it is best for you. We trust that you take the responsibility for the information safety, possible damage of data due to incompatible versions, and loss of time seriously and that you will follow the security bulletins and take your system out of operation immediately if it is likely to lead to a problem. I hope you understand that such configurations may require a longer time until we can fix issues arising from such configurations.

A list of things which recommend you to verify on your own:

```
* Backup schedules
* Virus scanner
...
```

Best Regards,
   your support

Comment: -1. This kind of advice is passive-aggressive, doesn't help the OP do their job, and may be reasonably construed as the OP saying they're not going to do their job. It doesn't solve this problem and would cause others, potentially worse.

Comment: The answer fits the OP's desire to express himself without getting fired, so it aimed at what he wants. Contains a "cover your ass", expresses the willingness to help further, and makes it clear that problems may arise. If i would have dealt with it differently from the beginning is another question.